# Cant able to access my selector in angular js mouseover event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I cant able to access the li element inside the div . I added mouseover event to li but it binds to its parent div only.

### HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul class="rating">
           <li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star" ng-click="toggle($index)"       
              ng-mouseover="starHover($index)" id="$index"> \u2605'
           </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### JS Directive link mouseover function:

```
scope.starHover = function(index) 
{
     elem.addClass('unfill').removeClass('filled');
}
```

I want to access the li that I mouseover and the nextAll li's also.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it in scope , do it in directive. Change your `li` tag like  this:

```
 <li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star" ng-click="toggle($index)" id="$index" mousable >  <!-- ... -->  </li>
```

And create `mousable` directive like this:

```
 yourApp.directive('mousable', function () {    
     return {       
         link: function(scope, element, attrs , ctrl) {
               element.bind("mouseover", function(e){    
                     element.addClass('unfill').removeClass('filled');
               });
               element.bind("mouseout", function(e){
                     element.addClass('filled').removeClass('unfill');
               });    
          }
      }
  }
```

References:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element 
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 1):

Do it the angular way:

```
<div>
    <ul class="rating">
           <li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="{star: true, unfill: hovered, filled: !hovered}" ng-click="toggle($index)"       
              ng-mouseenter="hovered = true" ng-mouseleave="hovered = false" id="$index"> \u2605'
           </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AVCT4/

Comment: I know that this is an old answere but i just want to say that the directive implementation provided by Cherniv is better because you can reuse that code.